# Total amount of bank loans in a country

Tags: data-request, banking

I am looking for total amount of customer loans banks are giving in a country. I can find data for US at 
http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/CLSACBW027SBOG

However I am looking for statistics for also other countries, Europe, China, Russia, Japan, India, etc.

Comment: I'd be interested in the Europe answers

Comment: I'd edit the title to "Total amount of bank loans in a country"

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the Bank for International Settlements? The stats are pretty comprehensive: https://www.bis.org/statistics/rppb1501.htm